# How to use Evaluate for dates?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I evaluate dates, as seen as below?

[image]

[image]

According to this list, https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php, all the functions in the formula should be valid.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, instead [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: Why are you using `Evaluate` at all? `Evaluate` should be passed Excel worksheet formulas, not VBA functions.

Comment: I thought it was more giving to show the resultat.

Comment: I'm using it to evaluate custom formulas

Comment: `DateSerial` is a VBA function - you can't use that within `Evaluate`. The worksheet function would be `Date`.

Comment: I think this would be easier with `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you want to use `Evaluate`, but the issue is the use of `DateSerial`. `Evaluate` should be used with worksheet formulas, not VBA functions.

The equivalent worksheet formula to `DateSerial` is [`Date`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349).